Uploading from OneDrive/Sharepoint in Laravel App
I'm looking for a solution to allow users to authenticate then upload files from their Sharepoint/OneDrive to S3 within a Laravel application. Has anyone been able to accomplish this before?
I've only conducted research thus far, and read various suggestions -- AppFlow, Graph API, etc.
